# Error while installing gem: Faye- Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

ERROR:  Error installing faye:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /home/path/../ruby extconf.rb

checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for port.h... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile
```

version details 
Rails 2.3.14, ruby 1.8.7

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing a native binary.  It looks like you are using Linux, it could be openssl that you are missing.

You can install openssl with `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` or the equivalent in your package manager.

You will find a full trace of what went wrong in `your_gem_path/.gems/faye/ext/gem_make.out`

Comment: thnx for quick response, but even after installing redis-server i am getting same error. contents of gem_make.out file are http://pastebin.com/Y7SpzxxM

Comment: Going by that output, it looks like you may be missing sqlite?  Try `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3`

Comment: Ahhh, it looks like you are missing openssl.  `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto`  Try installing `libssl-dev`

Comment: i was following railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye but got stuck because of above error. not getting what am i missing.. :(

Comment: okay i will try installing libssl-dev too. i will comment the output once i install it.  thnx a lot for quick responses..

Comment: thnx Gazler. i was missing libssl-dev. on installing it i could install the gem successfully..though i could not understand why ssl library is required. dependency of ssl is not mentioned in faye documentation.

Comment: Faye has an option to respond to SSL.  I would assume that is why it is required.  http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html